# json_decode for specific execution time depth

Tags: php, json

I have the following requirement;

I have the following sample of data;

```
{
    "username" : "aras", 
    "id" : 2, 
    "report" : {
        "reportId" : 5, 
        "reportFields" : {json array}
    } 
}
```

I want to decode the data as the following;

```
[username] => aras
[id] => 2
[report] => array(
    reportId => 5,
    reportFields => {json array} // which should be string only
```

I have looked at `json_decode()` 's depth. it is not about changing the execution of depth.

How can I solve this ?

NOTE : I need efficient solutions. High performance is needed in my project

Comment: If you need efficient solutions then handcraft a parser that reads up to the point you want to parse, reads backwards from the end to find the two closing braces and manually constructs an array. Take everything that remains and stuff it into a string.

Comment: is {json array} a placeholder for a json array (['val1', 'val2']) or is it actual the data? If so: should't it be quoted: "{json array}"

Comment: @TomLous {json array} is like [{'val1'}, {'val2'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `json_decode`, you could try and extract the "not to be decoded" field with a regexp, then `json_decode` the modified variable, and finally reassign the extracted item into the resulting array.

The regexp `/"reportFields"\s*:\s*(.*)}\s*}\s*$/ms` ought to match the item and return the lower-level array element. Replace the whole match with `"reportFields": "" } }` and you get a JSON entity that can be decoded and re-enriched.

Alternatively, you can extract "aras", 2 and 5 as independent strings with the same `preg_match` and not run `preg_replace` or `json_decode` at all.

Technically using regexps is **DEAD WRONG** because a JSON dictionary could contain the items *in any order*, while the regexp I supplied only recognizes the fields *in a specific order* - there should be around twelve possible orders? - and will fail if that order is not matched.

Usually, though, JSON producers tend to supply answers always in the same order. But do check that this is the case.

```
<?php

        $json = <<<JSON {
    "username" : "aras",
    "id" : 2,
    "report" : {
        "reportId" : 5,
        "reportFields" : {json array}
    } } JSON;
        preg_match('#^\\s*{\\s*"username"\\s*:\\s*"(.*?)",\\s*'
                   .'"id"\\s*:\\s*(\d+),\\s*'
                   .'"report"\\s*:\\s{\\s*"reportId"\\s*:\\s*(\d+),'
                   .'\\s*"reportFields"\\s*:\\s*{(.*?)}\\s*}\\s*}\\s*$#sm',
                        $json,
                        $gregs);
   $ar = array( 'username' => $gregs[1],
                 'id' => $gregs[2],
                 'report' => array(
                   'reportId' => $gregs[3],
                   'reportFields' => $gregs[4] ));

    print_r($ar);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [username] => aras
    [id] => 2
    [report] => Array
        (
            [reportId] => 5
            [reportFields] => json array
        )

)
```

### Note

Depending on the size and structure of json_array, the "recursive decode, then reencode `$ar['report']['reportFields']`" solution might be more performant (in addition to being far more maintainable):

```
$ar = json_decode($json);
$ar['report']['reportFields'] = json_encode($ar['report']['reportFields']);
```

If `json_array` is not too complicated, I'd avoid the regexp solution.

### Testing performances

Apparently, the regexp solution is (in practice) never more than twice as fast as the JSON solution, at most.

So, if there's a chance that the regexp has to be **maintained** (i.e. the JSON format might change), I'd **definitely** use the JSON version.

```
<?php

        $z = array('test');

        for ($items = 1; $items < 100; $items++)
        {
                $z[]    = "test-$items";
                $j      = json_encode($z);

                $json = <<<JSON
{
    "username" : "aras",
    "id" : 2,
    "report" : {
        "reportId" : 5,
        "reportFields" : $j
    }
}
JSON;
                if ($items % 10)
                        continue;

                $ITER = 100000;
                $a = microtime(True);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $ITER; $i++) {
                        preg_match('#^\\s*{\\s*"username"\\s*:\\s*"(.*?)",\\s*'
                                   .'"id"\\s*:\\s*(\d+),\\s*'
                                   .'"report"\\s*:\\s{\\s*"reportId"\\s*:\\s*(\d+),'
                                   .'\\s*"reportFields"\\s*:\\s*([[].*?[]])\\s*}\\s*}\\s*$#sm',
                                        $json,
                                        $gregs);
                        $ar = array( 'username' => $gregs[1],
                                     'id' => $gregs[2],
                                     'report' => array( 'reportId' => $gregs[3], 'reportFields' => $gregs[4] ));
                }
                $b = microtime(True);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $ITER; $i++) {
                        $ar = json_decode($json, True);
                        $ar['report']['reportFields'] = json_encode($ar['report']['reportFields']);
                }
                $c = microtime(True);
                $s1 = number_format(1000000*($b-$a)/$ITER, 2);
                $s2 = number_format(1000000*($c-$b)/$ITER, 2);
                $r  = $s1/$s2;
                print "$items items, regexp: $s1 million op/s, JSON: $s2 million op/s, ratio=$r\n";
        }
?>
```

The output (partial):

```
10 items, regexp: 6.65 million op/s, JSON: 8.25 million op/s, ratio=0.806060606060606144
20 items, regexp: 8.47 million op/s, JSON: 12.00 million op/s, ratio=0.705833333333333424
30 items, regexp: 9.93 million op/s, JSON: 15.54 million op/s, ratio=0.638996138996139051
40 items, regexp: 11.85 million op/s, JSON: 19.11 million op/s, ratio=0.620094191522762905
50 items, regexp: 13.46 million op/s, JSON: 22.68 million op/s, ratio=0.593474426807760191
60 items, regexp: 15.18 million op/s, JSON: 26.74 million op/s, ratio=0.567688855646970802
70 items, regexp: 16.85 million op/s, JSON: 30.35 million op/s, ratio=0.555189456342668919
```

The regexp solution scales better, but it takes a quite long json_array to make it *almost* twice as fast as the JSON solution. For typical short inputs the JSON solution is 80% as fast as the regexp, and *way* simpler and more maintainable.